# Single Post subscription not working in my meteor code

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I want to display only single elements based on the ID passed. I am using the subscribe and publish method of meteor for the same, also FlowRouter for Routing. When i try to get the data using findOne and pass the Id, it does't return any data, but when i do find({}), it gets all the data and displays it, not sure why findOne is not working..

Note : I am trying to fetch record based on the Object ID(_id) provided by MongoDB.

```
posts = Mongo.collection("allPosts");

<Template name="stdSingleView">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    {{#with studenthistory}}
    {{id}} - {{name}}
    {{/with}}
    {{else}}
    Loading....
    {{/if}} 
</Template>

Template.stdSingleView.onCreated(function(){
var self = this;
self.autorun(function(){
var Id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
self.subscribe('singlePost', Id);
});
});

Template.stdSingleView.helpers({
studenthistory: function(){
var id= FlowRouter.getParam('id');
return posts.findOne({_id: id});
}
});

if (Meteor.isServer) {
Meteor.publish("allposts", function() {
return posts.find({});
});

Meteor.publish('singlePost', function(id) {
check(id, String);
return posts.find({_id: id});
});
}

pages.route( '/:id', {
name: 'singleView',
action: function( params ) {
BlazeLayout.render('stdSingleView');
}
});
```

Comment: How can you `but when i do find({}), it gets all the data and displays it,`  with the  `{{#with studenthistory}}` ?

Comment: find is working for me too, but I need to do findOne, as I need to show only one record, which is not working. Pls see the full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/3s6zL5hg/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do findOne using _id, Please wrap it to the New Mongo.ObjectID and then pass it.

Try this code :

```
  Meteor.publish('singleStudent', function(id) {
    check(id, String);
    return attendanceRegCol.find({"_id": new Mongo.ObjectID(id)});
  });

  Template.studentSingleView.helpers({
    studenthistory: function(){
      var id= FlowRouter.getParam('id');
      return attendanceRegCol.findOne({"_id": new Mongo.ObjectID(id)});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sharath! Worked for me :)

Comment: odd ... not sure why i never use that but it still work with my project +1

Answer (score 1):

`find` will return a cursor, which contains only one document. You need to loop through that in order to get the data, or You change the helper into `findOne`

```
Template.stdSingleView.helpers({
    studenthistory: function(){
        var id= FlowRouter.getParam('id');
        return posts.findOne({_id: id});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tran for the reply. I was using findOne itself, but it was not working. So had switched to find, while I pasted the code here. findOne did not work.

Comment: the best way is trying to debug steps by steps. Can you try to: print out the `id` on the publication/print out the `posts.find({_id: id});` in the publication/on the page, open the `Chrome console` and type `posts.find().fetch()` to see if there is any data on the client ?

Comment: HI I tried consoling, the posts.find().fetch(). And it is giving empty array. tried printing posts.find({_id: id}); it's showing an object and the selector is "{{5694f3869e8dfbde5d74438a}}"

Comment: In Server Code , in publish method i consoled this -> console.log(attendanceRegCol.find({_id: id}).fetch()); even this gives the empty array